# Does pubnub affect the concurrency of my rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pubnub

I read from [railscast #401](http://railscasts.com/episodes/401-actioncontroller-live?view=comments) that having long living connections actually takes up the threads in rails server. And puma server can optimally take on may be 20-30 conncurrent connections.. Does that mean I will have to spin off many Heroku instances for my rails application to support (e.g. 1K - 5K people chatting?).

Or is it not affecting because all the chat connections are directly connceted to Pubnub's server?

Comment: Hi Chris, answer to the question would be different basing on your implementation. If you initialise just one Pubnub Client in your app, it'll be keeping open just one or two connections at most (one for subscribe events and another for non-subscribe events). Also, are you sure you want to pass the whole traffic through your server? Wouldn't it be easer for you to use JS SDK on client side for chatting, so the client's browser connects directly to our servers, reducing load on your side?

Comment: Chris, as Tomasz pointed out, why do you need your Heroku/Rails server app involved in the chats? Why not just have the JavaScript clients (your customers) chat to each other peer-to-peer as is the intent of this sort of use case. There are some valid use cases where you want your server involved but I might advise a different approach. Please provide further details about why you need your server involved in the chats.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, your end users (browser clients) will connect (publish/subscribe) through PubNub without involving your server.

In other words, you do not need to have your Rails/server act as a subscriber. Just serve up the web page with [the appropriate PubNub JavaScript](http://www.pubnub.com/docs/web-javascript/pubnub-javascript-sdk) for you clients to chat with each other directly without involving your server.

This image from one of the examples in the links below is a good illustration

[image]

Here are some links that should be helpful:

- https://github.com/ready4god2513/ChatterBee
- http://blog.htbx.net/blog/2012/10/04/real-time-voting-with-pubnub/
- https://github.com/pubnub/ruby/tree/master/examples/pubnub_livestream
- [Rails + Pubnub Integration Architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965076/rails-pubnub-integration-architecture)